# How can I remove part of a text containing a delimited block of special characters?

Tags: linux, string, bash, shell

I have a block of 100 strings of text and I must delete part of every string, i.e., delete 10 characters starting with `-it`, and leave the rest.

This is the string:

```
<a href="lyudmila<sup>-it48ceer3</sup>/index.html" target="_self" ref="title">< redincontri >**

<a href="cerco-una-donna-scopo-matrimonio-it9734n7n/index.html" target="_self" ref="title">< redincontri >
<a href="serio-carino-alto-188-m-ironico-per-bella-donna-al-massimo-di-48-anni-si-whatsapp<sup>-it7xda7k8</sup>/index.html
```

The character sequences to remove start in `-it` and are 10 characters long.

I have tried with sed and with grep, but with no result.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like so with sed using the `-E` option to enable extended regular expressions:

```
sed -E 's/-it\w{7}//g' input.txt > output.txt
```